# What types can be declared as const?

Tags: c#, types, constants

In C#, which are the types that can be declared as `const` ?

```
const int i = 0;
const double d = 0;
const decimal m = 0;
const referenceType = null;
```

Is there a comprehensive list I can refer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) clearly states that

> A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at
>   compile time. Therefore, the only possible values for constants of
>   reference types are string and null.

From section 10.4 of C# language specification. These are the types that can be used.

> The type specified in a constant declaration must be sbyte, byte,
>   short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal,
>   bool, string, an enum-type, or a reference-type. Each
>   constant-expression must yield a value of the target type or of a type
>   that can be converted to the target type by an implicit conversion

Comment: Yes that's section 10.4 in spec! accepting this for correctness!

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:

Constants are immutable values which are known at compile time and do not change for the life of the program. Constants are declared with the const modifier. **Only the C# built-in types (excluding System.Object) may be declared as const**. For a list of the built-in types, see Built-In Types Table (C# Reference). User-defined types, including classes, structs, and arrays, cannot be const. Use the readonly modifier to create a class, struct, or array that is initialized one time at runtime (for example in a constructor) and thereafter cannot be changed.

C# does not support const methods, properties, or events.

complete link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx

Comment: I don't think the documentation makes much sense (spec does) imo. `System.Object` and any other reference type can be declared as `const` (except they point to null).

Answer (score 0):

> In the context of C#, a constant is a type of field or local variable
>   whose value is set at compile time and can never be changed at run
>   time. It is similar to a variable by having a name, a value, and a
>   memory location. However, it differs from the variable by its
>   characteristic of getting initialized only once in the application. A
>   constant is declared using the keyword "const".

[Constants (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx)

Only the C# built-in types (excluding System.Object) may be declared as const. For a list of the built-in types, see  [***Built-In Types Table (C# Reference)***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx).

- bool byte sbyte char decimal double float int uint long ulong object
  short ushort string

Comment: I don't think the documentation makes much sense (spec does) imo. `System.Object` and any other reference type can be declared as `const` (except they point to null).